# FetchSize Equivalent in System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, odp.net, system.data.oracleclient

In **Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader** we have property called "**FetchSize**". 
Is there anything with same functionality in "***System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader***". Could any one suggested.